# Css right top corner

Tags: css

Hello how can i move a div class to the right top corner of a page without make the page longer on the side ?

my css code:

```
.nav ul {
list-style: none;
text-align: center;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
position: absolute;
top:0px;
right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Can you add more of your code?  Possibly your HTML too? Here's a fiddle with the only information we have and it works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/7u95Lmgu/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7u95Lmgu/3/ Here you have mate

Comment: Looks like it's on the right to me: http://jsfiddle.net/7u95Lmgu/4/

Comment: Yeah but the page side is getting longer on the right

Comment: Strange, it's not adding more space for me.  What browser are you using?

Comment: im using google chrome

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening, but I think you may need to add more of your code, including all of your relevant HTML and CSS

Comment: here you have again : http://jsfiddle.net/rpqgLrnv/

Comment: Your updated fiddle shows us now what the problem is - the answer is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for giving the rest of your HTML and CSS.  The problem comes from the css line:

```
.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -5px;
}
```

Not sure why the margin is being displayed in the first place, but it seems your compensating for it with the `-5px`.  This is making your last list element 5px too far out of the frame.

What you **should** do is find out why the margins are being made in the first place and fix that.  If you can not find that, then add this line directly after your `.nav li {...}` style:

```
.nav li:last-of-type {
    margin-right:0;    
}
```

This will take the `-5px` margin off of the last list element.

[Here's an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rpqgLrnv/1/) to show the fix.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add the following css line

```
header{
    width: 700px;
}
```

Change the width to whatever width you want to have. If you don't set a width to your (block-)elements they will stretch out 100%. Also if you want it centered you would add `margin: 0 auto;`. The css would look as following:

```
header{
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: That method is just advanced cus you need to edit the width to get it exactly to the right top corner.